# I can't open oracle after i edited characterset

Tags: oracle

I edited my oracle's characterset with this query

```
Update props$ set value$=’AL16UTF16’ where name=’NLS_CHARACTERSET’;
Commit;
```

then, i did

```
shutdown immediate; 
startup;
```

But startup didn't success.
startup Success to mount. But fail open.
And oracle say to me **ora-00911** don't avail character.

I can't anything now. Because can't open oracle...

please talk to me any information and solution.
Thank you.

Comment: You can't change the character set by messing around with the system tables. You just wrecked your database and the only thing you can do is to restore your backup.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name // Thank you to your comment. I understand that the only solution is to restore backup. It is my huge failure in my career...Thank you!